# My Neural Network(multiple input, multiple output) is giving NaN Values

Tags: keras, deep-learning, training-data

[neuralnetwork architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3GmY.png)

I am currently trying to train my Neural Network and experiencing NaN values after a given point.

Input: State and Actions

Output : Value of the state  and probability of the Actions

The inputs have been normalised prior

state size = (87,)

action_size = (864,)

I am not able to understand why the NaN values occur after a while.

Inputs needed!

```
def normalize_data(self, input_state, legal_actions):
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    input_state = np.array(input_state).reshape(-1, 1)
    input_state = scaler.fit_transform(input_state)

    legal_actions = np.array(legal_actions).reshape(-1, 1)
    legal_actions = scaler.fit_transform(legal_actions)
    input_state = input_state.ravel()
    legal_actions = legal_actions.ravel()
    return input_state, legal_actions
```

```
def build_network(self):
    # incorporating Residual tower
    state_input = Input(shape=self.state_size, name='Feature_Vector')
    leg_actions = Input(shape=self.action_size, name='Legal Actions')

    t = concatenate([state_input, leg_actions])
    t = BatchNormalization()(t) 
    t = Dense(2340)(t) 
    t = Activation('relu')(t)
    t = Dropout(0.0)(t)

    a = leg_actions

    actions_prob = Dense(self.action_size[0],activation='softmax')(self.policy_head(t))
    action_probs_masked = Multiply()([actions_prob, a])
    layer = Lambda(lambda x1: x1 / K.sum(x1, axis=1)[:, None])
    action_logits_masked = layer(action_probs_masked)  # probability
    self.pi = action_logits_masked
    self.v = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='v')(self.value_head(t))


    self.model = Model(inputs=[state_input, leg_actions], outputs=[self.v, self.pi])
    plot_model(self.model, to_file='residual_tower_Productionline.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
    self.model.compile(loss=[self.mse, 'categorical_crossentropy'],optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001), metrics=['mae', 'accuracy'])
    print(self.model.summary())


    def value_head(self, input):
        x = Dense(100, name='Dense_valuehead')(input)enter image description here
        layer = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()
        x = layer(x)

        return x

    def policy_head(self, input):
        print('policy head')
        y = Dense(2160, name='Dense_policyhead')(input)
        layer = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()
        y = layer(y)

        return y
```

Comment: input_State: [  0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
   0.     0.     0.     7.     0.   100.65 114.68  83.25  49.46 100.65
 100.65 233.64 141.29 229.27  66.98 170.94 220.99 213.95 125.96 168.15
  54.22 211.75 222.75 213.4  138.6  201.3   36.3  232.1    0.   126.5
 140.8   94.6   39.6  161.7    0.   200.2  235.1   82.2   30.1  108.2
   0.   136.95  87.75 117.29  56.98 150.15 186.45]